# Implementing a Custom ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to create a layout manager similar to ViewPager, but I'm not sure about what the best way to implement it is.

Basically I want my views to look like this:

[image]

From there I want to transition to other views when the user swipes from any of the numbered rectangles on the sides. So, say, if the user swipes from view number 3 and to the left, I would like to transition to the following view:

[image]

Ideally, I would like the transitions to be similar to how ViewPager works (i.e. I want the transition to interact with your finger so that the transition progresses back and forth when the user moves his finger from left to right).

It seems like I will need to implement my own version of ViewPager, I'm just not sure how to go about doing this. I only need to handle a small number of simple views so I can probably get away with caching all of my views for better performance.

I know how to implement the code to detect the swipes and where in the view the swipe started, but I don't know what the proper way to implement the view transitions is and how to handle the states of all the different views.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.